# Where did the title "Road To Singapore" (1940) come from?

Tags: title, road-to-singapore

The first of a series of "Road To …" films, staring Bing Crosby, Bob Hope, and Dorothy Lamour, was *Road To Singapore*, in 1940.

Strangely, the characters never go to Singapore.
In fact, nowhere in the film is "Singapore" mentioned.

Why was it given that title?

Answer (score 1):

> Strangely, the characters never go to Singapore. In fact, nowhere in the film is "Singapore" mentioned.
>
> Why was it given that title?

No, it's not mentioned but that is where, in fact, they were **heading** (hence Road to Singpore)...before they get sidetracked.

> Josh and Ace flee to Hawaii and then head for Singapore.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_to_Singapore)

Comment: "*and then head to Singapore*" is an anonymous addition, given without citation (i.e. someone's possibly incorrect opinion).

Answer (score 0):

It's not as much where they are going – it's where they have been.

> Two playboys try to forget previous romances in Singapore - until they meet a beautiful dancer.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032993/

There are scenes and references to Singapore, though:

> They end up sharing a waterfront shack in Singapore and vying for the affections of a sarong-clad local (Lamour) ...

https://www.quotes.net/movies/road_to_singapore_9619

To be fair, though, all the Crosby - Hope "Road" movies have messy plots. Sometimes it's hard to be sure where the heck they are.

Comment: "*a waterfront shack in Singapore*" is someone's incorrect statement about the film.  They were in a Kaigoon, not Singapore.  Similarly "*try to forget previous romances in Singapore*" is also someone's opinion about what the film is about.

Comment: That's why I mentioned "messy plots." They talk about events preceding the movie's timeframe in that shack and are, supposedly, headed back there. The series is full of inconsistencies like that.